# How to get latitude and longitude at given bearing and given distance from a point

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Let say I have point **A(28.513393, 77.072276)** and bearing is **45 degree** then get point **B(?,?)** at distance **5 Km** from point **A** at given bearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate the position of point B you can use the 
[Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/). The utility library has a class `SphericalUtil` that allows to calculate distances, areas and headings via spherical geometry.

The method of `SphericalUtil` that should be used is the `computeOffset`. According to the documentation

> public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from,
>                                      double distance,
>                                      double heading)
>
> Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

source: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

So, the code snippet in your example is

```
LatLng pointA = new LatLng(28.513393, 77.072276);
double distance = 5000.0; //expressed in meters
double heading = 45.0  //expressed in degrees clockwise from north
LatLng pointB = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(pointA, distance, heading);
```

For more details follow setup guide of the utility library:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/setup

I hope this helps!